# Not able to run 'yarn start' after installing browserfy, webpack & terser globally

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tsconfig

I installed a number of packages globally to try and get NodeJS code bundled to import into a react project (I now know this is not possible)

- browserify
- terser

Now I have gone back to different React projects and I am getting the following error when I run `yarn start`, all these projects worked until I made these changes the other day

```
╰─ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
$ webpack serve --mode development --hot --port 3001
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/henrystevens/Documents/SolutionEngineering/SEDevelopment/se-plugin-omx/webpack.config.ts' config
[webpack-cli] webpack.config.ts:7:7 - error TS6133: 'BundleAnalyzerPlugin' is declared but its value is never read.

7 const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

If I comment out that line, because it says the BundleAnalyzerPlugin is not used, I get this error

```
╰─ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
$ webpack serve --mode development --hot --port 3001
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/henrystevens/Documents/SolutionEngineering/SEDevelopment/se-plugin-omx/webpack.config.ts' config
[webpack-cli] /Users/henrystevens/Documents/SolutionEngineering/SEDevelopment/se-plugin-omx/webpack.config.ts:2
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/henrystevens/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/henrystevens/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I think its has something to do with the updates I made for the other project, trying to get nodejs code to be useable in a React project, perhaps a global webpack or tsconfig file is causing this issue, but I'm not sure

This was the typical developer process, just install things until the POC works!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Manually removing my global `node_modules` folder worked

```
cd /usr/local/lib


rm -rf node_modules // Be very careful with this command! its a force remove function
```